# Android Calling wcf with Complex objects

Tags: android, wcf

I am trying to access wcf method using Complex objects

My WCF:

```
[OperationContract]
    List<acclist> ccAcc(cList cll);
```

Clist class:

```
public class cList
{

    [DataMember]
   public string state { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
   public string city { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string street { get; set; }


}
```

From Android  i need to call cccAcc so that i'm passing complex object
cList customList=new cList();

```
 PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            customList.setState("tn");
            customList.setCity("chennai");
     pi.setName("cll");
            pi.setValue(customList);
            pi.setType(cList.class);
request.addProperty(pi);
```

but my response is:
ccAccResponse{ccAccResult=anyType{}; } how to resolve this error.

Comment: In the code you've posted, did you omitted or is it missing the [DataContract] attribute in you cList class?

Comment: I have [DataContract] in my wcf cList class. here i didn't post that line.